# Is there a safe, yet unspoofed way of detecting a file type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, file-upload, file-type

I've searched all over the internet and the "safest" way to check uploaded file type seems to be checking magic numbers/headers using `python-magic` library

`magic.from_buffer(open("testdata/test.pdf").read(2048))` for in memory files

`magic.from_file("testdata/test.pdf", mime=True)` for files on disk

However what I also read everywhere that even magic bytes can be spoofed with a security consequences.

**Is there a safer way or at least another-layer-safe solution in python?**

(Preferrably, but not limited to, using Django)

PS: Stuff like "checking an extension" or "Content-type" header from user side - I don't consider a file type check ***at all***.

Comment: What threat are you trying to protect yourself from?  Any part of anything you download over the internet can be spoofed.  Fine, you've determined what you've downloaded really is a python program.  That doesn't prove to you that it's a safe Python program.

Comment: The idea is to verify it enough that it is not run as anything else but its target, if the target format is flawed itself, that's another story.